# java.io.FileNotFoundException with Jmeter - Using beanshell pre processor

Tags: file-io, jmeter, beanshell

I'm having issue with Jmeter using BeanShell PreProcessor to encode input file then include the encoded file in "Send file with request".

Jmeter Setup

---

- HTTP Request (Send file with the request - ${file1})

  - BeanShell PreProcessor

BeanShell PreProcessor

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
String file1 = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("D:/File/test.txt"),"UTF-8");
vars.put("file1",new String(Base64.encodeBase64(file.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
```

Error Message

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${file1} (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to do the following:

1. Read file into a string
2. Encode content to Base64
3. Save encoded content to another file
4. Save new file path into a JMeter Variable

your Beanshell code should look like:

```
String file1 = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("D:/File/test.txt"), "UTF-8");
FileUtils.write(new File("D:/File/testbase64.txt"),new String(Base64.encodeBase64(file1.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
vars.put("file1","D:/File/testbase64.txt");
```

Your code snippet was

1. Trying to put encoded file content into `file` JMeter variable
2. Having a typo in the last line `file.getBytes()` should be changed to `file1.getBytes()`

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on bsh scripting in Apache JMeter.

Comment: wow. Thanks Dmitri. Code snippet was from yours too. I added ref link in last line but I must have deleted when I was formatting code block :)